# Mapping values to dataframe from a different dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, mapping

**Problem**: I have 2 dataframes `df1` and `df2`. My goal is to modify `df1` by replacing some of its values if found within `df2`.

```
import pandas as pd

# dataframe 1
data = {'A':[90,20,30,25,50,60],
        'B':['qq','ee','rr','tt','ii','oo'],
        'C':['XX','VV','BB','NN','KK','JJ']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

# dataframe 2
convert_table = {'X': ['dd','ee','ff','gg','hh','ii','ll','mm','nn','oo','pp','qq','rr','ss','tt','uu'], 
                 'Y': ['DD','VV','FF','GG','HH','KK','LL','MM','NN','JJ','PP','XX','BB','SS','NN','LL'], 
                 'Z': [5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(convert_table)

# search values of df1 inside of df2 and replace values
for idx1,row1 in df1.iterrows():
    for idx2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
        if row1['B']==row2['X'] and row1['C']==row2['Y']:
            df1.replace(to_replace=row1['B'],value=row2['Z'],inplace=True)
```

As you can see I have 2 for loops and I check if the generic row of `df1` (`row1`) is found inside of `df2`. If this condition is met, then I replace the value contained in row1['B'] with the one contained in `row2['Z']`

Therefore the results that I get is (exactly what I would like to have as a result):

```
In [120]: df1
Out[120]: 
    A   B   C
0  90  43  XX
1  20   7  VV
2  30  47  BB
3  25  59  NN
4  50  19  KK
5  60  37  JJ
```

Notice how column B has changed.

**Question**: could you suggest me a better way to write my code? I would like to make it as fast as possible maybe by using the built-in functions offered by Pandas or Python.

**Note**: the data contained into the dataframes is just for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use merge on two columns:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on=['B','C'], right_on=['X','Y'], how='left')
```

The `how='left'` is critical here. Read [Brief primer on merge methods (relational algebra)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra) if you don't understand why.

I'll modify your example to create one where there's an entry in df1 that doesn't exist in df2, which is `('ii','KK')`

```
In [1]:
# dataframe 2
convert_table = {'X': ['dd','ee','ff','gg','hh','ll','mm','nn','oo','pp','qq','rr','ss','tt','uu'], 
                 'Y': ['DD','VV','FF','GG','HH','LL','MM','NN','JJ','PP','XX','BB','SS','NN','LL'], 
                 'Z': [5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,37,41,43,47,53,59,61]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(convert_table)



In [2]: merged = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['B','C'], right_on=['X','Y'], how='left')
        merged
Out[2]: 
    A   B   C    X    Y     Z
0  90  qq  XX   qq   XX  43.0
1  20  ee  VV   ee   VV   7.0
2  30  rr  BB   rr   BB  47.0
3  25  tt  NN   tt   NN  59.0
4  50  ii  KK  NaN  NaN   NaN
5  60  oo  JJ   oo   JJ  37.0
```

Now to retrieve the final dataframe:

```
In [3]:
merged.ix[merged.Z.notnull(),'B'] = merged.ix[merged.Z.notnull(),'Z']
merged = merged[['A','B','C']]
merged

Out[3]:
    A   B   C
0  90  43  XX
1  20   7  VV
2  30  47  BB
3  25  59  NN
4  50  ii  KK
5  60  37  JJ
```

Comment: Is it possible to get an output that has the same number of columns as the one I got in my example?

Comment: I just did this at the same time you posted your comment :)